# Let users to add any number of input fields in the theme option page

Tags: theme-development, settings-api

I've been creating a custom settings page for my own theme according to [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-settings-page-for-your-wordpress-theme--wp-20091).

What I want to know is how to let users to add any number of input fields.

Just like this image

[image]

I have already created what's in the image. But cannot save data in the database.

The article I was following was really good but at the end part it's little bit confusing where to add particular piece of code. So, may be I've messed with it.

If you guys have followed this particular article, it'd be great if you could help me how to do this according to this article itself, or another way of doing this.

Comment: Have you tried using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin? It does wonders.

Comment: No, I don't want to use a plugin here. Because, I'm developing a theme and that functionality MUST be comes with the theme.